# Trying to return a select statement which show records from two tables that match records from a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the Exercise we were given to practice our SQL refresher

Get all rows from TableA. If a match is available in both TableB and TableC, include it. This means that if data is available in TableB or TableC, but not both, data from both willbe excluded and only TableA data will be show

This is currently my full syntax I am using at the current moment.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.TableA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableC c ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.ID = c.ID
WHERE a.ID <100;
go
```

And this is the corresponding output I am getting.

[image: This is the said output from the syntax]

I am trying to change Column B record 2 into NULL as it does not match Column C. Is there anyway I can get something like this to work, if I try this in the syntax it throws an identifier can not be found.

```
LEFT JOIN  dbo.TableB b
on a.ID = b.ID and TableC.ID = b.ID
```

**Expecting**

- All From Table A
- Rows from TableB that match TableA and TableC
- Rows from TableC that match TableA and TableB

Comment: Can you also include your expected output?

Comment: provide some sample data and your desired output

Comment: Your question says you are using inner joins, but your query says you are using left joins.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen here is the exercise requirements for us to practice:                  
 Get all rows from TableA. If a match is available in both TableB and TableC, include it. This means that if data is available in TableB or TableC, but not both, data from both will be excluded and only TableA data will be show

Comment: Please try to learn [how this site works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) rather than applying norms from some other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my logic was a bit wrong.

I decided to try and layout the tables differently to see if that works and it ended up getting to what I needed

```
select *
from dbo.TableB b
inner join dbo.TableC c
on b.ID = c.ID
right outer join dbo.TableA a
on b.ID = a.ID
where a.ID < 100;
go
```

[image]